# iOS or Android: Javascript replace attribute value

Tags: javascript, android, ios, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I can easily replace value of html if I know id by writing something like this in android.

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('Login_loginField').value = 'joni'")
```

Problem is that now I have a bit complicated attribute like this.

```
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-label="Employee ID" aria-describedby="i.desc.1563426530 i.err.1563426530" name="entry.1911914324" value="" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="something" badinput="false" aria-invalid="false">
```

I don't know my id and I need to change data-initial-value if it is *something* . How shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the class name is unique, you can do the same by class name:

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementsByClassName('quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput')[0].value = 'joni'")
```

Comment: ah..i think we don't have control over class (it might be dynamic or more than once).  But we do have control for initial data (I can give as ***** symbol )